# OCI FetchInto does not fetch data in PHP 7

Tags: php, database, oracle

I am trying to fetch data from a table in oracle database using php 7. I am using OCIFetchInto but when i look to the result array, i find it empty, although it shouldn't be actually empty. knowing that the connection to the database is successful and the table in the database is not empty.

I have debugged the code, and i am getting Resource #4 from the execute function, I have changed the execute function but i still get the same result.

i also changed the data[0] to data['columnname'] but i still cannot retreive it.
Thanks in advance

The code below:

```
 require_once("../include_tse/class_ora_db.php");

$oracle_db = new ora_database("abc");


$error="";
if ($oracle_db->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
  echo "Connected successfully";





    $Wip=$_REQUEST['rechts'];
    echo $Wip;


    $sql_query="SELECT Om_Wip_Entity_Name,Quantity,Country_Description FROM abc_print WHERE Om_Wip_Entity_Name= '$Wip'";

$cursor = $oracle_db->execute_sql($sql_query);

$counter=0;



 while (OCIFetchInto ($cursor,$row))
  {
    echo "2222222";
    $data[]=$row;
    $Wip= $data['0'];
    $Quantity= $data['1'];
    $Country= $data['2'];

    $counter ++;
 }
 echo "row.$Quantity";
```

Comment: Since we don't know how your DB class works, we cannot help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of PHP 5.4 the `ocifetchinto` alias has been deprecated (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ocifetchinto.php)

You should change it to something like...

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc ($cursor))
  {
    $Wip= $row['Om_Wip_Entity_Name'];
    $Quantity= $row['Quantity'];
    $Country= $row['Country_Description'];

    $data[]=$row;

    $counter ++;
 }
```

I'm a bit confused as to how your using the data, but this should give a better idea of how to get it working.